# Template in template

Tags: java, templates

I've tried to create ArrayList that 'ill hold templated class, example:

```
public static ArrayList<Variable<float>>
```

That's code of my Variable Class:

```
public class Variable <T> {
    public T value;
    public String txt;
}
```

And it fails. I get `Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType` So how to fix it? I dont want to create separate classes, for example VariableFloat, VariableString etc.

Comment: What is the line that is giving you the error?

Comment: `public static ArrayList<Variable<String>>`

Comment: That's not a statement. You need to declare that ArrayList as as a variable or method.

Comment: It's declared like this:
`public static ArrayList<Variable<float>> iVars;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to do this:

```
public static ArrayList<Variable<float>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note the lower-case `float` which is a primitive type. Primitives are not allowed to be used as type-arguments in Java. Instead you should use `Float` wrapper class:

```
public static ArrayList<Variable<Float>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

The reason you're getting the "dimension" message is because it thinks you're trying to do this:

```
public static ArrayList<Variable<float[]>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which *is* allowed.

Comment: Yeah, compilers sometimes throw dumb messages.

Answer (score 0):

Generics cannot be with primitives, only with Objects. Use the wrapper class.

```
public static ArrayList<Variable<Float>> iVars;
```